# c++ with libpcap won't compile under windows

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, pcap, libpcap

First of all I'm quit new in programming in c/c++, so maybe it's just a basic error but i don't get it. The Problem is, I want to use libpcap in a bigger application, but i can't even integrate the libary into a simple HelloWorld.cpp. Atm I'm using Eclipse (MinGw Compiler) with Windows 64bit, but consindering to switch to Linux if my Problem(s) can't be solved.

Downloaded "libpcap-1.5.3.tar.gz" from tcpdump.org, extracted and added the root directory of the Libary to Eclipse (under "Properties/C|C++ Build" to all Compilers and to the MinGW Linker).
My Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pcap.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
cout << "Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints Hello World!!!
char *dev = argv[1];

printf("Device: %s\n", dev);
return(0);
}
```

First error:

```
D:\Tools\MinGW\lib\libpcap/pcap-stdinc.h:49:22: fatal error: bittypes.h: No such file or directory
```

So I changed line 49 from

```
#include "bittypes.h"
```

to

```
#include <Win32/Include/bittypes.h>
```

(the actual location of bittypes.h) and next error pops up:

```
D:\Tools\MinGW\lib\libpcap/pcap/pcap.h:451:1: error: 'Adapter' does not name a type
```

'Adapter' is defined in "pcap-int.h" so I included this header into "pcap.h" but now I get:

```
D:\Tools\MinGW\lib\libpcap/pcap-int.h:46:22: fatal error: Packet32.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
```

and this "Packet32.h" does not exist...

I can't belive this popular libary is broken, so where is my mistake? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to compile the Wireshark sources? WS uses libpcap and it can be compiled with VC++.

Comment: @harper True it does, but PCap can be compiled by itself.

Comment: @user3608078 What does your include path look like?

Comment: When you have a compiling project enabled "display include files". This shows you the header files that should be actually included. Further you have a blueprint for your include path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Problem is, I want to use libpcap in a bigger application, but i can't even integrate the libary into a simple HelloWorld.cpp. Atm I'm using Eclipse (MinGw Compiler) with Windows

If you want to use libpcap on Windows, you need a version of libpcap that's been ported to Windows.  The libpcap source won't build on Windows; on UNIXes, libpcap can and does use packet capture mechanisms built into the OS, but it doesn't do so on Windows (for one thing, older versions of Windows, at least, don't *have* a packet capture mechanism built in!), so it also needs a driver.

One port of libpcap to Windows is [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org); it includes the necessary driver.  If you install WinPcap, and then download the [WinPcap developer's pack](http://www.winpcap.org/devel.htm) and install it, it should be possible to configure Eclipse so that your program can be built with WinPcap.

Answer (score -2):

`libpcap-1.5.3.tar.gz` is a *source* package for the library, not a binary package.  So you need to build the library; you can't just add the directory to Eclipse and expect it to work.

The usual way to build a source package is to unpack it into a directory and look for a file called `README` or `INSTALL`, which is a simple text file containing instructions on how to build and install the package for various machines.  Often there will be multiple such files for different platforms.

Generally, there will be a script called `configure` that you run to create a Makefile for your target; then you run `make` to build the code and `make install` to install it in a standard place so that other packages can find it.

Comment: This is not at all what the OP is trying to do.